# Why does `at` not execute GUI applications?

Tags: at

On my Ubuntu 20 desktop, I've scheduled `gedit` to run a minute from now, but nothing happens. Why is that?

```
$ echo "echo foo > at.sux" | at now + 1
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 8 at Tue Jun  2 21:47:00 2020

$ echo `which gedit` | at now + 1
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 9 at Tue Jun  2 21:47:00 2020

$ atq
9   Tue Jun  2 21:47:00 2020 a dandv
8   Tue Jun  2 21:47:00 2020 a dandv

# A minute later

$ cat at.sux
foo

$ ps auxf | grep gedit  # nothing but grep

$ `which gedit`  # launches gedit
```

I tried `echo "gedit &" | at now + 1` as suggested in the comment, but `gedit` is still not running a minute later.

Comment: Tried `&`, no difference on Ubuntu. Edited the question. `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUI applications access the screen through a server. When you run them from the command line or the menu, the environment tells the application how to connect to the server.

When you run an `at` command though, the environment does not include that information (you can do `at -c JOBNUMBER` to see the environment the application inherits) and that's why the application will start, but not be able to run.

To run a GUI application you could specify the server, either calling the application with something this (your display might be different):

```
DISPLAY=:0 application
```

or, depending on the application:

```
application --display :0
```

You might need to change the server permissions and other services might be needed and not accessible from outside the session though (things like dbus).

Comment: `echo "DISPLAY=:0 gedit" | at now + 1 min` worked!

Comment: `echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit" | at now + 1 min` should be more portable.

Answer (score 0):

GUI applications such as `gedit` may or may not work with the `at` command. It depends on whether you are using an X11-based display server such as `Xorg` or a server based on the `Wayland` protocol such as `Weston`.

Which display server is used depends on your distribution, the version of the distribution, and user configuration.  For example, by default, Ubuntu 20 uses an X11-based display server whereas Fedora 32 uses Wayland.

The `at` command stores most of your current environment in a `at` job file under `/var/spool/at`. There are a few exceptions including DISPLAY, TERM, SHELLOPTS, EUID, GROUPS, PPID, UID, and a couple more.  These are specifically not stored in the `at` job file.

Thus, if you create an `at` job to launch a GUI application in an X11-based server environment, it will fail because no `DISPLAY` variable is available.

The workaround is simple (assuming your screen is `:0`):

```
$ echo 'DISPLAY=:0 gedit' | at now + 1 min
```

or more generally:

```
$ echo 'DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" gedit' | at now + 1 min
```

Wayland uses a different environmental variable, i.e. `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, which is typically set to `wayland-0`. The `at` command preserves this variable and, thus, the GUI application is launched when the `at` job runs.